# Get Jenkins Job's parameter using REST API?

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to fetch all the jenkins job using rest API, but can't figure out how to get the parameters of a job. The output should be parameter names, like this REST API's output -

> http://localhost:8080/api/json?tree=jobs[name]&pretty

Output:

```
{
  "_class" : "hudson.model.Hudson",
  "jobs" : [
    {
      "_class" : "hudson.model.FreeStyleProject",
      "name" : "PowerShellTest"
    },
    {
      "_class" : "com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder",
      "name" : "Production"
    },
    {
      "_class" : "hudson.model.FreeStyleProject",
      "name" : "Test"
    },
    {
      "_class" : "com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder",
      "name" : "TestFolder"
    },
    {
      "_class" : "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob",
      "name" : "TestPipeline"
    }
  ]
}
```

This only list job's name, I want Job's parameters' list too, is there any way ?

P.S - I dont need the last successful build's parameters, I only want to get the job's parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be achieved like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/json?tree=jobs[name,color,url,actions[parameterDefinitions[name]],property[parameterDefinitions[name]]]&pretty
```

There are two sub queries for the different project types:

- `actions[parameterDefinitions[name]]` - for freestyle projects
- `property[parameterDefinitions[name]]` - for pipeline projects

Comment: Thanks, this helped, also this can be done in a single query as "localhost:8080/api/json?tree=jobs[name,color,url,actions[parameterDefinitions[name]]]&pretty"

Comment: @AbhishekPal Thanks, it's great that it works with a single query. I had to add `property[parameterDefinitions[name]]` to get parameters for pipeline projects too.

Comment: Thanks for this comment, this really helped, I've been looking now to get the parameter for Pipeline Jobs and I found this. Thanks.